# Open chrome:// URL's from the command line?

Tags: google-chrome

You can open a URL in chrome from the command line with:

```
google-chrome https://example.com
```

Is there a way to open `chrome://` URL's (such as `chrome://bookmarks/`) in this manner?  When I try to open a `chrome://` URL from the shell, chrome simply opens an empty browser tab.

It wouldn't be surprising if Chrome simply refuses to as a matter of user protection.  If that happens to be the case: where is this documented?

Comment: I want to do the same but ran into the same problem. I even tried to use a dedicated HTML page with JavaScript to browse to the Chrome URL but it failed with console error `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://extensions/`.

Comment: Any update ? I want to find a solution for this problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2023: Worked with chrome 113, current [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/) on Debian sid:

```
$BROWSER& sleep 2 #Opens a new tab in your hopefully already running browser.
xdotool type --delay 111 $URL #Don't type each letter too fast!
xdotool key Return
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Only thing, on my Google Chrome108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (64-bit), it opens a new Chrome window rather than a new tab. Any way to make it open a new tab?

Comment: These commands open my chrome:// URL in a new tab: ```xdotool search --class chrome windowactivate -- key ctrl+t``` and
```xdotool search --class chrome windowactivate -- type chrome://net-internals/#dns``` and
```xdotool search --class chrome windowactivate -- key Return```  I put them in a shell script that runs them in sequence.  They send to Chrome: ctrl+t, chrome URL, Return.

Comment: The 2020 solution I posted above totally fails now with 2023 chrome. It even types the words into the URL bar jumbled. Sorry. Total flop.

Comment: xdotool didn't change in that regard afaik, so most likely your setup changed, not the solution. Perhaps you need to also focus the url bar with F6 beforehand. It works for me to say the least.

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes F6 moved the cursor out of the URL bar. Anyway I can type without misspellings in other fields, but not the URL bar. In the URL bar, even e.g.,
xdotool type chrome;
sleep 1;
xdotool type ://;
sleep 1;
xdotool type settings/;
sleep 1;
xdotool type passwords;
sleep 1; results in those words getting typed in half misspelled. Like my cat walked on my keyboard.

Comment: OK, I made a fresh version of the script, for 2023!